# how to add an additional view to the display menu for allI DexterityContent types

Tags: plone

I have created a view that is available to all IDexterityContent types via @@myview.
But I also would like to add it to the display menu of IDexterityContent types.

Update:
To be more precise I'd like TTW create dexterity types to have this view available in the display menu.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea?  You might create some side-effects for other add-ons and content types that you do not intend.  Why a goal so broad as all IDexterityContent type instances?

Comment: What kind of side-effects are we talking about? The only thing that comes to my mind is a naming conflict if the add-on uses the same view name.

Comment: It is not likely a good idea to force all possible Dexterity-based types to get an action that may or may not be appropriate to their specific case.  It would be better to use a marker interface (via behavior) and make this kind of user-interface glue an opt-in feature.

Comment: You are right. A behavior/marker interface is a good idea to make this optional. But I still don't know what side effects might hit me.

Comment: @sdupton: the side effect would be that the view is listed in the display menu, hardly a problem, really.

Comment: Don't get me wrong -- I don't think this is really a problem for an add-on that is only used internally on a site; it just limits future re-use in other contexts in the play-nice-with-others department.  For TTW types, @MikkoOhtamaa's answer is likely best, though you may need to use an event subscriber to modify the factory type information when the schema or its fields are modified (I do not believe any other events are notified when editing types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available views for a content which support dynamic views option are stored in the site database, portal_factory

https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/dynamic_views.html

If you want to add support for multiple views I suggest you create an installer Python snippet which will iterate portal_factory for available types and modifies their view_methods attribute.

https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/types.html#type-information-registry

https://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/genericsetup.html#custom-installer-code-setuphandlers-py

Comment: Sadly iterating over existing types does not (completely) solve my problem. I'd like the menu entry to be available to future (marked) dexterity types that are create TTW.

Comment: You need to add a hook which is executed every time TTW type is added. I suggest you contact Dexterity authors to see what kind of hooks are available and what kind hooks need to be added to solve your needs.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: schema editor notifies some events like IObjectModifiedEvent, IIRC.  This may be a place for which hooks could be used to modify the FTI (I believe that the context obtained from the events may be a TypeSchemaContext object from plone.app.dexterity -- its 'title' attribute may contain the FTI name).